# Curiosity and curiousness

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the words curiosity and curiousness? How and when do you use them?

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curiosity) has:

> **curiosity** [noun]
>
> B2 [ U ] an eager wish to know or learn about something:
>
> - *to arouse/excite/satisfy someone's curiosity*
> - *I'm burning with curiosity - you must tell me who won!*
> - *She decided to call her ex-boyfriend out of curiosity.*
> - *"Why do you ask?" "Oh, just idle curiosity (= for no particular reason)."*
>
> ...
>
> **curiosity** [noun] (STRANGE OBJECT) [C]
>
> something that is interesting because it is rare and unusual:
>
> - *Cars like mine are curiosities nowadays.*

but no entry for 'curiousness'. Is the latter a valid word?

Comment: I'm not aware that 'curiousness' is a legitimate word.

Answer (score 3):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/curiousness) has:

> **curiousness**: an eager desire to find out about things that are often none of one's business
>
> *Children have a natural curiousness about everything.*
>
> Synonyms of curiousness: curiosity, inquisitiveness, nosiness

This is inadequate, and doesn't bring out the degree of overlap between 'curiousness' and 'curiosity'.

[WordNet/Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/curiousness) allows the two main senses:

> 1. **curiousness** – a state of active curiosity – inquisitiveness, curiosity, wonder – a state in which you want to learn more about
>    something – nosiness, prying, snoopiness – offensive inquisitiveness
> 2. **curiousness** – the quality of being alien or not native; "the strangeness of a foreigner"

........

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/curiousity) licenses both these main senses for 'curiosity' also:

> **curiosity n**
>
> 1. an eager desire to know; inquisitiveness
>
> 2.a. the quality of being curious; strangeness

While I'd prefer 'curiosity' for 'inquisitiveness', and (if pushed) 'curiousness' for 'strangeness' (the 'curiouser and curiouser sense), there is a large degree of overlap.

The count-noun usage, whether concrete

- *"What's this dusty old curiosity on the mantelpiece?"*

or abstract

> - *It is a little known curiosity of history that the French and English garrisons, technically at war with each other, mounted combined actions against* ...

['The Unusual Life of Tristan Smith' ... Peter Carrey](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curiosity)]

*must* be 'curiosity'.

Answer (score -1):

See the following words. Adjectives ending in -ous can have their noun form by adding -ness or -osity

scrupulous - scrupulosity - scrupulousness 
virtuous - virtuosity - virtuousness 
luminous - luminosity - luminousness 
curious - curiosity - curiousness 
generous - generosity - generousness
religious - religiosity - religiousness

There are many more cases. Though in all the cases given osity is more common. In many of these the ending -ness may be considered incorrect, though I've searched and they do have entries in dictionaries.
As for the difference of curiousness vs curiosity, or the -ousness or -osity, all I know is that you might sound weird using the one or the other, particularly -ousness with the above examples.